# Change which python im using in terminal MacOs Catalina

Tags: python, macos, terminal, anaconda

First of all, im really new at Machine Learning and Anaconda
Recently I´ve Installed Anaconda for MachineLearning but now when i try to run my old scripts from my terminal, all my packages are not there, even pip or numpy or pygame y don´t know how to change to my old python directory, I really don´t know how this works, please help me. I´m on MacOs Catalina

Comment: Some advice to manage multiple python versions: Maintain virtual environments.


A good suggestion for conda is to create a list of separate virtual environment with different python versions.

Let's say you need a python venv with python 3.6.8

`conda create -n my_venv_py368 python==3.6.8`

When you want to use a particular venv,

`conda activate my_venv_py368`

If you need the list of all the available conda envs.

`conda env list`

Comment: Are you using Conda?

Answer (score 3):

The reason this is happening is because Python 2.7 was officially deprecated by MacOS in Catalina. Python 3 is the stable release and is installed by default on MacOS now.

The reason your old scripts and packages don't work and your package manager and Python modules are missing is likely because you're now operating in a Python 3 environment. You can check this with the following command:

```
$> python --version
Python 2.7.16
```

The correct way to go about this is to create a [Python Virtual Environment](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/) in your project space and set up a requirements file to install your dependencies for that project and enter that virtual environment when you want to work with that project.

[Here's](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac) a document detailing the ways someone might install and switch to Python 3 on MacOS. If you take the logic and invert it you could switch to Python 2 instead. Which I do not recommend. Instead you should refactor your apps to run on Python 3 because 2.7 was officially retired on January 1st, 2020 and is [no longer maintained.](https://github.com/python/devguide/pull/344)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, Python 3 is integrated in `macOS X Catalina`, just type `python3`. For `pip`, you can use `pip3`. Personally, I would prefer native over `conda` when using mac.

Next, you need to get all the modules up from your previous machine by `pip freeze > requirements.txt` or `pip3 freeze > requirements.txt`

If you have the list already, either it's from your previous machine or from a GitHub project repo, just install it via `pip3` in your terminal: `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

If not, you have to manually install via `pip3`, for example: `pip3 install pygame` etc.

After all dependencies are done installed, just run your `.py` file as usual.

Last, but not least, welcome to the macOS X family!